# Tests for Basic Python Data Structure Interfaces

Tags: python, testing, data-structures

A fairly small question: does anyone know about a pre-made suite of Python unit tests that just check if a class conforms to one of the standard Python data structure interfaces (e.g., lists, sets, dictionaries, queues, etc).   It's not overly hard to write them, but I'd hate to bother doing so if someone has already done this.  It seems like very basic functionality that someone has probably done already.

The use case is that I am using a factory pattern to create data structures due to different restrictions related to platforms.  As such, I need to be able to test that the resulting created objects still conform to the standard interfaces on the surface.  Also, I should note that by "conform" I mean that the tests should check not just that the interface functions exist, but also check that they work (e.g., can set and retrieve a value in a map, for instance).  Python 2.7 tests would be preferred.

Comment: I am yet to see a good usecase for Factories in python

Comment: Not aware of any pre-made, but like you say, not too difficult to roll your own using the ABC's in `collections`

Comment: As a side note, `queue` is not a data structure in the way you're thinking, because its key feature is its multithreading features: all operations are atomic, and it provides a way to let producers or consumers block on each other.

Comment: Agreed that queue is not quite a data structure.  However, it is one of the types that I expect the factory to need to provide, so I listed it.

Comment: @Namey: But if you're just checking the protocol of queue, that's pretty much useless. If it's not appropriate synchronized, it's not a queue.

Comment: @Pykler: There are _lots_ of good use cases for factories in Python. It's just that factories are so trivial in Python that, even when it's blatantly obvious (the parameter name for `collections.defaultdict` is `default_factory`, and `open` is defined as a factory that returns file objects), you don't even notice that there are factories. Most notably, almost every class object is a singleton concrete factory for that class, so all the boilerplate people put into building singleton concrete factory objects in Java comes for free.

Comment: @abarnert: Indeed.  What I am looking for is to not just check that the functions exist, but to actually test that said functions work appropriately.  For a queue, having said multithreading capabilities is part of its specification as a data structure in Python.  Hence, an appropriate set of tests would test that proper sequences of function calls result in proper outputs in a multithreaded test.

Comment: @abarnert that is true, but creating instances is not called a factory in Python or in Java even if it was a "factory" pattern. What I mean is people writing functions that instantiate classes and return instances, that kind of code is never justified in python or at least I have not yet seen a use case for it.

Comment: @Pykler: Again, almost every class is a function that instantiates a class (itself) and returns an instance. And there are plenty of functions that can instantiate different classes depending on their parameters or on other program state, and return instances—see `codecs.open`, `urllib2.request`, or in 3.x plain old `open`. How are these not factories?

Comment: @Namey: In that case, I think what you want is something even more poorly defined, no matter how intuitively obvious it is. Believe it or not, there is nothing that defines what "work appropriately" means for an ABC method—but it's a pretty good guess that "does the same thing as the only builtin concrete implementation of that ABC" is what you actually want, or at least very close to it. So, I think you've made the right choice.

Comment: @Namey: As for Queue, I still strongly believe you should think of that separately from the collections… but I guess it doesn't matter that much if you're going with "cannibalize CPython's unit test suite", because `test_queue.py` is obviously in the same place as `test_dict.py`, and structured the same way. (By the way, IIRC, there's some extra complexity to handle `dummy_thread` which you'll want to strip out, unless you care about platforms without threading.)

Comment: @abarnert: Definitely "Works appropriately" is vague.  In this case, it means "To the consumer of said object, functionality is equivalent to the original Python version so long as you only use the functions from the interface."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, "the standard Python data structure interfaces" are not lists, sets, dictionaries, queues, etc. Those are specific implementations of the interfaces. (And queue isn't even a data structure in the sense you're thinking of—its salient features are that its operations are atomic, and `put` and `get` optionally synchronize on a `Condition`, and so on.)

Anyway, the interfaces are defined in five different not-quite-compatible ways.

---

The [Built-in Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) section of the documentation describes what it means to be an iterator type, a sequence type, etc. However, these are not nearly as rigorous as you'd expect for reference documentation (at least if you're used to, say, C++ or Java).

I'm not aware of any tests for such a thing, so I think you'd have to build them from scratch.

---

The `collections` module contains [Collections Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) that define the interfaces, and provide a way to register "virtual subclasses" via the [`abc` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#module-abc). So, you can declare "I am a mapping" by inheriting from `collections.Mapping`, or calling `collections.Mapping.register`. But that doesn't actually prove that you *are* a mapping, just that you're claiming to be. (If you inherit from `Mapping`, it also acts as a mixin that helps you complete the interface by implementing, e.g., `__contains__` on top of `__getitem__`.)

If you want to test the ABC meaning, defuz's answer is very close, and with a little more work I think he or someone else can complete it.

---

The CPython C API defines an [Abstract Objects Layer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/abstract.html). While this is not actually authoritative for the language, it's obviously intended that the C-API protocols and the language-level interfaces are supposed to match. And, unlike the latter, the former are rigorously defined. And of course the source code from [CPython 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/), and maybe other implementations like [PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/release-2.0.0//pypy/objspace), may help.

There are tests for this that come with CPython, but really, they're for testing that calling `PyMapping_GetItem` from C properly calls your `mymapping.__getitem__` in Python, which is really at a tangent to what you want to test, so I don't think it will help much.

---

The actual concrete classes have additional interface on top of the protocols, that you may want to test, but that's harder to describe. In particular, the way the `__new__` and `__init__` methods work is often important. Implementing the `Mapping` protocol means someone can construct an empty `Foo` instance and add items to it with `foo[key] = value`, but it *doesn't* mean someone can construct `Foo(key=value)`, or `Foo({key: value})` or `Foo([(key, value)])`.

And for this case, there *are* existing tests that come with all of the standard Python implementations. CPython comes with a very extensive test suite that includes things like [`test_dict.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/test/test_dict.py). PyPy runs all the (Python-level) CPython tests, and some extra ones besides.

You will obviously have to modify these tests to run on an arbitrary class instead of one hardcoded into the tests, and you may also have to modify them to handle whichever definition you pick.  Plus, they probably test *more* than you asked for. You just want to know if a class conforms to the protocol, not whether its methods do the right thing, right? But still, I think they're a good starting point.

---

Finally, the C API defines a [Concrete Objects Layer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/concrete.html) that, although it's not authoritative, matches the previous definition and is more rigorously defined.

Unfortunately, the tests for this one are *definitely* not going to be very useful to you, because they're checking things like whether `PyDict_Check` and `PyDict_GetItem` work on your class, which they will not for any mapping defined in pure Python.

---

If you do build something complete for any of these definitions, I would strongly suggest putting it on PyPI, and posting about it to python-list, so you get feedback (and bug reports).

Comment: A few notes:
1. For my purposes, the most important thing would be tests that could accommodate any of the virtual subclasses in the collections abc, plus Queue.
2. test_dict.py is very close to the mark.  With some minor edits, it could be useful I think.
3. If no one has done it, I'll probably end up creating them based on the CPython tests.
4. The \__new__, \__init__, any teardown stuff wouldn't need to be tested by these.  I can always subclass the tests to add extra checks for those implementation-specific functions.

Comment: I'm accepting this one as good enough.  I've taken some of the cPython tests and torn out some of the basic dependencies.  After that, I'll make it so that they are all designed to compare two arbitrary classes that are both class variables for the test.  That way, using a list as an example, I can have one class be a list and the other an arbitrary class that should act like a list from the outside (and subclasses of the test can just override the class to be tested).

Answer (score 0):

There are [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) in standart module `collections` based on ABC module.

You have to inherit your classes from these classes to be sure that your classes correspond to the standard behavior:

```
import collections

class MyDict(collections.Mapping):
    ...
```

Also, your can test already existed class that does not obviously inherit the abstract class:

```
class MyPerfectDict(object):
    ... realization ...

def is_inherit(cls, abstract):
    try:
        class Test(abstract, cls): pass
        test = Test()
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

is_inherit(MyPerfectDict, Mapping) # False
is_inherit(dict, Mapping) # True
```

Comment: True, but I don't think it helps directly. For example, if I build a class that perfectly conforms to the `Mapping` interface, but doesn't inherit from or register with `collections.Mapping`, how can `collections` help you decide whether my class is acceptable?

Comment: @abarnert, I think I found a way to do it, even though it was not very nice

Comment: This doesn't really help. If `MyPerfectDict` doesn't actually implement the `Mapping` protocol, your test will still pass.

Comment: @abarnert, this particular example works correctly, but there are problems with build-ins classes, such as `int`. I do not understand why.

Comment: I think you have to define either `Test.__new__` or `Test.__init__` to make sure the ABC's methods get called, and then it _will_ work for all classes (even builtin types)… but let me experiment before you trust that vague recollection…

Comment: As it stands, `is_inherit(dict, Mapping)` isn't true because it's checking the protocol, but because it's true for all builtins (and classes that subvert the metaclass by defining `__new__`): `is_inherit(int, Mapping)` is also true. And if it's false for `MyPerfectDict`, then it's not even working for the simple case…

Comment: Reversing the order to `Test(cls, abstract)` fixes the problem with `MyPerfectDict`, but doesn't help for the other problems.

Comment: OK, got it. You need to do the test two different ways. For "friendly" classes, what you have is correct (except that you have the subclasses backward). For "unfriendly" classes (including builtin/extension types, old-style classes, classes with bizarre metaclasses, and classes that define `__new__`), the best you can do is to check the abstract methods directly. So, http://pastebin.com/kmTv2hyd should do it. You can pretty easily deliberately subvert the test by building a class that will fail when it shouldn't, but I can't think of a way for it to fail by accident.